# Organizar arquivos JavaScript de um projeto

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, organização-de-projeto

Estou trabalhando em um Sistema Web com várias telas e elas possuem diferentes funções em Javascript e várias se aplicam apenas a uma página. Como organizo os arquivos Javascript? Qual a melhor prática?

- Criar um arquivo para cada página
- Criar um arquivo com todas as funções
- Outra maneira?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A organização dos seus arquivos depende do tipo do projeto, tamanho, módulos existentes, etc... Procure identificar se as suas funções javascripts podem ser agrupadas em diferentes arquivos, por exemplo:

Em um projeto você tem:

- Funções utilitárias para string, date e números.
- Funções de validação de dados
- Funções de processamento

Aí a sua estrutura pode ficar parecida com:

< seuProjeto

     < js

         < utils

                 < stringUtils.js

                 < numberUtils.js

                 < dateUtils.js

         < validation

                 < ....js

                 < ....js

         < process

                 < ....js

                 < ....js

Assim, agrupamos nossos arquivos em arquivos diferentes e em diretórios diferentes. O projeto ficou bem dividido e intuitivo. É só um exemplo de organização para você ter uma ideia de como montar a sua estrutura.

**EDIT: Gerenciadores**

Dependendo da estrutura do seu projeto, é indicado utilizar gerenciadores de arquivos para facilitar o seu trabalho. Em alguns projetos em que eu utilizo `AngularJS`, eu costumo utilizar o `RequireJS`. O `RequireJS` gerencia todas as dependências dos arquivos .js importando eles quando necessário.

Leia a respeito dele [aqui](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html). Nesse link também fala a respeito de **otimização**.

Comment: Pesquisando sobre, me indicaram bastante a organização que você comentou, mas me recomendaram usar algum tipo de automatizador para minificar meus arquivos JS. Trabalho com .NET e encontrei http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification

Comment: Sim, pois facilitará o gerenciamento dos arquivos. veja a edição da resposta